# ngModel is not working when using in dynamic data scenario?

Tags: angular, checkbox, dynamic, checkboxlist, ngmodel

Actually I am trying to create a custom datatable by using the Angular 4 cli and the JSON arrays. I have successfully created the table with dynamic column and the dynamic rows. so, that I want to fix a filter column for the table by using the dropdown checkbox style. Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn" dropdown>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdownToggle>Filter
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" *dropdownMenu>
          <div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let column of columns, let i = index" >
              <label for="column">
                <input [(ngModel)]="column" type="checkbox" id="column" name="column" value="column" checked="true"> {{column}}
              </label>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And my component.ts file code is:

```
StudentsDetails = [];

  columns: string[] = [];

  constructor(private newService: StudentsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newService.fetchData()
    .subscribe(responseStudentsDetails => {
      this.StudentsDetails = responseStudentsDetails;
      this.columns = Object.keys(this.StudentsDetails[0]);
    })
  };
```

So, when I am trying to call the [(ngModel)]="column". It shows me the Error like: [Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlD5U.png)

Comment: Are You imported `FormsModule` like `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`

Comment: Yes I am imported FromsModule.

Comment: In Your Component do have `column` property?

Comment: Yes I have. But now my problem how to bind the multiple checkbox checked data to some other component. help to to solve this issue.@SalimIbrogimov

Comment: The answer below is correct isn't it?

Comment: yes of course, That's worked for me. But I want to bind the checked data from the multiple checkboxes. Any ideas.?

Comment: Do You want to create new array of checked items?

Comment: Yes ofcourse .. That's my point. help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I think, You should use `checked` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some limitations how you can use variables defined by `*ngFor`.

You can work around using:

```ts
[(ngModel)]="columns[i]"
```

Comment: @VigneshMohanraj thanks for the edit. Didn't look properly. Glad to hear it works for you.

Comment: Actually your comment is worked fine. But How I want to bind these checked data from the checkboxes to some another component.@Gunter Zochbauer

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment. What other component? You can either bind to an `@Input() myInput;` using `<some-component [myInput]="column[i]"` or implement `ControlValueAccessor` in `SomeComponent` to be able to use it with `[(ngModel)]="..."` (not sure this is what you ask for)

Comment: When you edited my answer, you changed `columns` to `column`, that wasn't my intention. It should be `columns` (with `s`)

Comment: Actually I need to create a new array of checked items @Gunter Zochbauer

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. A "new array" for what purpose? With what data?

Comment: I want to store the checked items into an array for filter the columns in the tables. @Gunter Zochbauer

Comment: You can use `<input type=!checkbox" [ngModel]="columns[i]" (ngModelChange)="checkedItems.push({index: i, checked: true})">` where `{index: i, checked: true}` is just a random example at what you might want to add to the `checkedItems` array.